# How to pass multiple id's in query string

Tags: php

I have a link in which I want to pass multiple values but, not sure how. If I just pass $id then the query string works but not with $title.

My code:

```
<td><a href="VotingPoll.php?id='.$id.'?title='.$title.'"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-small">VIEW</button></a></td>
```

Comment: https://eval.in/955742

Comment: thank you splash58, but how can we access that array stored values?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just send multiple query params with the same name:

```
<td><a href="VotingPoll.php?id='.$id.'&id='.$id2.'&title='.$title.'"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-small">VIEW</button></a></td>
```

Comment: Only the last `id` will be available you would need to use an array `id[]` for multiple.

Comment: You might have a problem with your web server, I tested with a Jersey rest endpoint, and receiving as a '@QueryParam' with List<String> type it receives the multiple values ok @AbraCadaver

Comment: This is PHP which will give you only 1 `id`.